# Copy a node from parent to child

Tags: xslt-1.0

I would like to copy a parent node into the child but I'm unsure on how to proceed.

I apologize in advanced for the weird looking source file, I'm new to this forum and have no clue on how to properly paste an XML file.

My XML source file is like this:

> `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
>   `<IncidentLogUpload>`
>
> > `<Header>`
> >
> > > `<BatchID>2013</BatchID>`
> > >       `<SystemID>2013</SystemID>`
> > >       `<DateTime>12/20/2013 3:37 PM</DateTime>`
> >
> > `</Header>`
> >
> > `<Item>`
> >
> > > `<IncidentLogs>`
> > >
> > > > `<IncidentLog>`
> > > >
> > > > > `<IncidentSource>Source</IncidentSource>`
> > > > >               `<Property>Property</Property>`
> > > > >               `<Location>B1</Location>`
> > > > >                           `<SubLocation/>`
> > > > >           `<DailyLogID>IN2013</DailyLogID>`
> > > > >           `<IncidentID>IN2013</IncidentID>`
> > > > >           `<Reference/>`
> > > > >           `<DateTimeOccured>12/19/2013 8:17 PM</DateTimeOccured>`
> > > > >           `<IncidentType>Surveillance</IncidentType>`
> > > > >           `<Specific>Observation</Specific>`
> > > > >           `<Category>POI</Category>`
> > > > >           `<IncidentDetails>0400</IncidentDetails>`
> > > > >           `<RelatedIncidentNo/>`
> > > > >           `<DateTimeReported>12/19/2013 8:17 PM</DateTimeReported>`
> > > > >           `<ParticipantSubjectProfiles>`
> > > > >
> > > > > > `<ParticipantSubjectProfile>`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > `<FirstName>James</FirstName>`
> > > > > > >               `<MiddleName></MiddleName>`
> > > > > > >               `<LastName>Henderson</LastName>`
> > > > > > >               `<ParticipantType>Subject</ParticipantType>`
> > > > > > >               `<MembershipNumber></MembershipNumber>`
> > > > > > >               `<DriversLicense></DriversLicense>`
> > > > > > >               `<PassportNumber></PassportNumber>`
> > > > > > >               `<IncidentID>IN2013</IncidentID>`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > `</ParticipantSubjectProfile>`
> > > > >
> > > > > `</ParticipantSubjectProfiles>`
> > > > >           `<ParticipantPersonnelProfiles>`
> > > > >
> > > > > > `<ParticipantPersonnelProfile>`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > `<BusinessUnit>Games</BusinessUnit>`
> > > > > > >               `<FirstName>Edison</FirstName>`
> > > > > > >               `<MiddleName>John</MiddleName>`
> > > > > > >               `<LastName>Costabile</LastName>`
> > > > > > >               `<CSELNumber/>`
> > > > > > >               `<StaffID>000408</StaffID>`
> > > > > > >               `<DriversLicense/>`
> > > > > > >               `<AffBUKey>GamesIN2013</AffBUKey>`
> > > > > > >               `<ParticipantType>Personnel</ParticipantType>`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > `</ParticipantPersonnelProfile>`
> > > > >
> > > > > `</ParticipantPersonnelProfiles>`
> > > >
> > > > `</IncidentLog>`
> > >
> > > `</IncidentLogs>`
> >
> > `</Item>`
> >
> > `<Footer>`
> >
> > > `<NumberOfRecords>5</NumberOfRecords>`
> >
> > `</Footer>`
>
> `</IncidentLogUpload>`

I would like to copy the `<Property>` node to both `<ParticipantSubjectProfile>` and `<ParticipantPersonnelProfile>`. The end result should be like this:

> `<ParticipantSubjectProfiles>`
>
> > `<ParticipantSubjectProfile>`
> >
> > > `<FirstName>James</FirstName>`
> > >       `<MiddleName></MiddleName>`
> > >       `<LastName>Henderson</LastName>`
> > >       `<ParticipantType>Subject</ParticipantType>`
> > >       `<MembershipNumber></MembershipNumber>`
> > >       `<DriversLicense></DriversLicense>`
> > >       `<PassportNumber></PassportNumber>`
> > >       `<IncidentID>IN2013</IncidentID>`
> > >       `<Property>Property</Property>`
> >
> > `</ParticipantSubjectProfile>`
>
> `</ParticipantSubjectProfiles>`
>   `<ParticipantPersonnelProfiles>`
>
> > `<ParticipantPersonnelProfile>`
> >
> > > `<BusinessUnit>Games</BusinessUnit>`
> > >       `<FirstName>Edison</FirstName>`
> > >       `<MiddleName>John</MiddleName>`
> > >       `<LastName>Costabile</LastName>`
> > >       `<CSELNumber/>`
> > >       `<StaffID>000408</StaffID>`
> > >       `<DriversLicense/>`
> > >       `<AffBUKey>GamesIN2013</AffBUKey>`
> > >       `<ParticipantType>Personnel</ParticipantType>`
> > >       `<Property>Property</Property>`
> >
> > `</ParticipantPersonnelProfile>`
>
> `</ParticipantPersonnelProfiles>`

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ParticipantSubjectProfiles>
        <xsl:for-each select="IncidentLogUpload/Item/IncidentLogs/IncidentLog/ParticipantSubjectProfiles">

    <ParticipantSubjectProfile>  
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <MiddleName></MiddleName>
        <LastName>Henderson</LastName>
        <ParticipantType>Subject</ParticipantType>
        <MembershipNumber></MembershipNumber>
        <DriversLicense></DriversLicense>
        <PassportNumber></PassportNumber>
        <IncidentID>IN2013</IncidentID>
        <Property> <xsl:value-of select="/IncidentLogUpload/Item/IncidentLogs/IncidentLog/Property"/></Property>
    </ParticipantSubjectProfile>

    </xsl:for-each>
</ParticipantSubjectProfiles>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this template out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <ParticipantSubjectProfiles>
        <xsl:for-each select="//ParticipantSubjectProfiles/ParticipantSubjectProfile">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../preceding-sibling::Property"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ParticipantSubjectProfiles>
    <ParticipantPersonnelProfiles>
        <xsl:for-each select="//ParticipantPersonnelProfiles/ParticipantPersonnelProfile">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../preceding-sibling::Property"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </ParticipantPersonnelProfiles>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```